# EF is mapping to the wrong keys on entities

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, fluent

When I run a linq query it's trying to map the SchoolInfo.SchoolInfoId to the SchoolId.SchoolId.

How do I define the correct mapping so it knows to map SchoolInfo.SchoolId to School.SchoolId?

This is Code-First.

SQL Tables

```
table School
(
    int SchoolId not null PK
)

table SchoolInfo
(
    int SchoolInfoId not null PK
    int SchoolId not null FK
)
```

Models

```
class School
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    int schoolId;

    virtual SchoolInfo SchoolInfo;
}

class SchoolInfo
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    int schoolInfoId;

    int schoolId;

    virtual School School
}

modelBuilder.Entity<School>().HasOptional(a => a.SchoolInfo).WithRequired(a => a.School);
```

Comment: The title says, is *not* mapping to the *wrong* keys on entities? Do you mean single/double negation?

Comment: ok, clarified.. :)

Comment: Are you in CodeFirst or Model/DatabaseFirst ?

Comment: @romain-aga Code-first

Comment: This relationship is correct? One to Many? Or you means One to [Zero Or]One?

Comment: @PedroFernandesFilho zero or one to one. SchoolInfo is not always there and is an optional record.

Comment: It would be more appropriate you put the key SchoolInfoId in School table/Model as nullable. It is possible?

Comment: @PedroFernandesFilho It doesn't exist in the database that way.

Comment: If you can not change the database ... In this case, you can remove the `Key` DataAnnotation from `SchoolInfo.SchoolInfoId`and put in `SchoolInfo.SchoolId`?

Comment: @PedroFernandesFilho This did work but what about my actual primary key on that table, now it doesn't match up?

Comment: The actual modeling in database allow One to Many. As we are trying to do One to One, we disregarded the `SchoolInfoId` field. Indeed, if the system create more than one record with the same `SchooId` on this table, you will have a problem. The way I see it, your best choice would be to model EF representing the reality of your database model (i.e.: One to MAny).

Comment: It's a optional one to one relationship

Comment: No, unless the `SchoolInfo.ShcoolId` field has some constraint to be unique, it is not. If `SchoolInfo` table can have more than one record with the same value in the `ShcoolId` field you will end up having N (many) children.

Comment: @PedroFernandesFilho I've added the unique constraint to that table to make it a one to one in the DB but I'm still getting the same errors.

Comment: Ok, add a constraint gives an workaround to the relationship's modeling. However, the EF is not yet able to understand an workaround, if you can not change the database modeling, you have to do make a workaround in the EF mapping (placing the DataAnnotation `Key` in `SchoolInfo.SchoolId` property.

Comment: @PedroFernandesFilho I've also tried to add a nullable SchoolInfoId column to the School table and still doesn't work. Can you give some code examples?

Comment: This scenari looks like a classic Table Splitting (horizontal splitting) for me. You should have one sql table with school field and schooInfo field which go on two entity (mapped on different column of the sql table except for the ID) and having a one to one Association between them. Using two table should be used when two school could share their schoolInfo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more appropriate way to do is something like:

Data Base:

```
TABLE School (
    INT SchoolId NOT NULL PK
)

TABLE SchoolInfo (
    INT SchoolId NOT NULL PK -- FK
)
```

School Model:

```
public class School
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int schoolId { get; set; }

    public virtual SchoolInfo SchoolInfo { get; set; }
}
```

SchoolInfo Model Option 1:

```
public class SchoolInfo
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("School")]
    public int schoolId { get; set; }

    public virtual School School { get; set; }
}
```

SchoolInfo Model Option 2:

```
public class SchoolInfo
{
    [ForeignKey("School")]
    public int SchoolInfoId { get; set; }

    public virtual School School { get; set; }
}
```

SchoolInfo Model Option 3:

```
public class SchoolInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int schoolId { get; set; }

    public virtual School School { get; set; }
}

// Relationship:

modelBuilder.Entity<School>().HasOptional(a => a.SchoolInfo).WithRequired(a => a.School);
```

**An alternative way because of the restrictions you mentioned is something like:**

Your actual Data Base:

```
TABLE School (
    INT SchoolId NOT NULL PK
)

TABLE SchoolInfo (
    INT SchoolInfoId NULL PK
    INT SchoolId NOT NULL FK -- WITH UNIQUE CONSTRAINT TO ENSUERE ONE TO ONE
)
```

School Model:

```
public class School
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int schoolId { get; set; }

    public virtual SchoolInfo SchoolInfo { get; set; }
}
```

SchoolInfo Model Option 1:

```
public class SchoolInfo
{
    public int schoolInfoId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int schoolId { get; set; }

    public virtual School School { get; set; }
}

// Relationship:

modelBuilder.Entity<School>().HasOptional(a => a.SchoolInfo).WithRequired(a => a.School);
```

SchoolInfo Model Option 2 (I did not test it):

```
public class SchoolInfo
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int schoolInfoId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("School")]
    public int schoolId { get; set; }

    public virtual School School { get; set; }
}

// Relationship:

modelBuilder.Entity<School>().HasOptional(a => a.SchoolInfo).WithRequired(a => a.School);
```

You can see:

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: I looked and I would have to update tons more code to add this column to the DB which is not possible right now. Is there a way to get the above working with Fluent or data annotations?