# EF6 how to map this zero or one to one relationship

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, fluent

This is Code-First.

What's the correct Fluent or data annotation for this relationship?

Getting EF mapping error:
Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Model.SchoolInfo' and 'Model.School'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

If I add

```
modelBuilder.Entity<School>().HasOptional(s => s.SchoolInfo).WithRequired(ss => ss.School);
```

I get this error:
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation: School_SchoolInfo_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'School_SchoolInfo_Target' in relationship 'School_SchoolInfo'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

SQL Tables

```
table School
(
    int SchoolId not null PK
)

table SchoolInfo
(
    int SchoolInfoId not null PK IDENTITY
    int SchoolId not null FK UNIQUE
)
```

Models

```
class School
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    int schoolId;

    virtual SchoolInfo SchoolInfo;
}

class SchoolInfo
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    int schoolInfoId;

    int schoolId;

    virtual School School
}
```

Comment: Why do you ask the same question [twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349886/ef-is-mapping-to-the-wrong-keys-on-entities)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to implement **1:1 mapping**, this is how tables should look like:

[image: Schools]

[image: SchoolInfoes]

And your entity classes in that case would look like this:

```
public class School
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }

    public virtual SchoolInfo SchoolInfo { get; set; }
}

public class SchoolInfo
{
    [ForeignKey("School")]
    public int SchoolInfoId { get; set; }

    public virtual School School { get; set; }
}
```

Your current table structure suggests **1:M mapping**, and in order to map entity classes to it, you need to do slight changes:

```
public class School
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SchoolId;

    public virtual IList<SchoolInfo> SchoolInfoes { get; set; }
}

public class SchoolInfo
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SchoolInfoId { get; set; }

    public int SchoolId { get; set; }

    public virtual School School { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I need to keep both SchoolId and SchoolInfoId on the SchoolInfo model

Comment: @user3953989 If you keep SchoolId in SchoolInfo class, you are setting up 1:M relationship. Is that your goal? If you are setting up 1:1, then your SchoolInfoId in SchoolInfo class shares same value as SchoolId in School class.

Comment: I've added a UNIQUE constraint to the SchoolInfo table SchoolId column which should make it a one-to-one on the DB side. Unfortunately I would to refactor a ton of code to change to a proper one-to-one which I cannot do currently.

Comment: @user3953989 Check my edit about Fluent API. If you are keeping the structure, then you have to say it is 1:M relationship. You also have to specify that there are multiple SchoolInfo in School class (added IList).

Comment: CS1061 'TTargetEntity' does not contain a definition for 'School' and no extension method 'School' accepting a first argument of type 'TTargetEntity' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) With the Fluent change

Comment: @user3953989 Have you updated your classes as well to match my edited post?

Comment: I did not see where SchoolInfo was changed to a collection, which would mean I'd need to refactor all the other code that currently accesses it.

Comment: @user3953989 You will have to change something. Your tables are set up to be 1:M. So either fix tables to be 1:1 or fix code to be 1:M. I am sorry but I really can't help you much than this.

Comment: How would I change them to a proper one to one for these models?

Comment: @user3953989 I have updated post to show both scenarios. First scenario is how 1:1 mapping is properly done. Second scenario is what should your entity classes look like to support your current SQL tables structure. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider reviewing your entity-relationship data model. Try removing the SchoolInfoId field (you don't actually need it), and just using the school ID FK as a PK. That will make your data model consistent.

Comment: I can't in this case